# Status bar comes back when uiimagepickercontroller called

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

Until iOS 5 update, i had no status bar issue. Now, when UIImagePickerConroller is called, status bar comes back although i set it initially hidden in plist file.

Also i tried;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

is it iOS 5 bug? Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem.

I don't know if it's an iOS 5 bug or wanted behaviour, but I found that setting :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

when the problem may happen is the temporary solution. Cause I don't know if this will be solved. Perhaps it's wanted by Apple. So...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone]; 
[self.navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480)]; 
}
```

and if you have navigationBar:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having a WTF moment just now while testing with iOS5 sim.